# Huge minimum algorithm execution time difference when running the same program multiple times on the same data

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, x86

I was testing one of my programs and noticed the different execution time between program runs.
I have found some issues, but after all still the same program with the same input data may execute twice slower. I have tested my program on Windows 10 (with Intel Skylake 8700k on board) and two compilers: Visual Studio 2019 and llvm for windows. Results were similar for both compilers (just different times).

Finally I have created simple program to reproduce the issue (attached below).
I'm really curious what cause such a huge performance difference. 
I have already fixed **false sharing** on `vector<vector<myData>>` (it was on vector member variables), but the main problem still exists.

### The Benchmark

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

struct pr{
    unsigned short a, b, c;
    pr() = default;
    pr(int a, int b, int c)
        : a((unsigned short)a)
        , b((unsigned short)b)
        , c((unsigned short)c)
    {}
};

struct image{
    image(unsigned short w, unsigned short h){
        data = new unsigned char[w * h];
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    ~image(){
        delete[] data;
    }
    unsigned char* Row(int row){
        return data + row * width;
    }
    unsigned char* data;
    unsigned short width;
    unsigned short height;
};

//align to prevent false sharing
struct alignas(64) myData
{
    vector<pr> data;
};

vector<myData> buffer;
void Process(image& inImage, vector<pr>& outResult)
{
    //allocate some temporary buffers
    //don't release memory between iterations
    //just clear at the end of the function
    while (buffer.size() < 20)
        buffer.resize(20);
    outResult.clear(); //clear result

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int i = 0; i < inImage.height; ++i)
    {
        //get buffer based on thread id
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        vector<pr>& localout = id == 0 ? outResult : buffer[id].data;

        //perform some computations to fill buffers
        unsigned char* data = inImage.Row(i);
        int begin = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < inImage.width; ++j)
        {
            if (data[j] < 20) begin = j;
            else if (data[j] > 190)
                localout.emplace_back(j, i, j - begin);
        }
    }

    //combine partial results
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); ++i)
        outResult.insert(outResult.end(), buffer[i].data.begin(), buffer[i].data.end());

    for (auto& item : buffer)
        item.data.clear();
}

int main()
{
    image img{ 1000, 1000 };

    //init with some random values
    srand(123);
    for (int i = 0; i < img.height; ++i){
        unsigned char* row = img.Row(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < img.width; ++j)
            row[j] = (unsigned char)(rand() % 256);
    }

    //measure execution time and display best result
    vector<pr> result;
    std::chrono::milliseconds minTime = std::chrono::milliseconds::max();
    for(int it = 0; true; ++it){
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            Process(img, result);
        auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(finish - start);

        if (d < minTime){
            minTime = d;
            printf("min: %lld ms\n", minTime.count());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Finally after running the program several times I receive such sample outputs:

**Run 1**

```
min: 101 ms
min: 90 ms
min: 87 ms
min: 86 ms
min: 85 ms
min: 84 ms
min: 82 ms
min: 81 ms
min: 80 ms
min: 79 ms
```

**Run 2**

```
min: 66 ms
min: 51 ms
min: 50 ms
min: 49 ms
min: 48 ms
```

**Run 3**

```
min: 101 ms
min: 93 ms
min: 92 ms
min: 88 ms
```

**Run 4**

```
min: 130 ms
min: 122 ms
min: 120 ms
min: 119 ms
min: 118 ms
```

When the minimum execution time was big like 118 then the program was running much longer (so I waited if it is possible to get better result, but without any significant improvement)

As we can see the minimum execution time difference is huge (48ms best case vs 118ms worst case). I have also recorded average time. it behaves in a similar way.

When recording data with VTune I see the program is L3 bound (when program runs slow). In both cases I execute program with the same data and access the data with fully predictable pattern. So what cause such a big slow down ? How to prevent it ?

**Edit (based on comments below)**

Thanks to @PeterCordes comment finally the program runs always fast. The optimized version:

```
void Process(image& inImage, vector<pr>& outResult)
{
    //allocate some temporary buffers
    //don't release memory between iterations
    //just clear at the end of the function
    while (buffer.size() < 20)
        buffer.resize(20);
    outResult.clear(); //clear result

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int i = 0; i < inImage.height; ++i)
    {
        //get buffer based on thread id
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        vector<pr> localout = std::move(id == 0 ? outResult : buffer[id].data);

        //perform some computations to fill buffers
        unsigned char* data = inImage.Row(i);
        int width = inImage.width;
        int begin = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            if (data[j] < 20) begin = j;
            else if (data[j] > 190)
                localout.emplace_back(j, i, j - begin);
        }

        localout.swap(id == 0 ? outResult : buffer[id].data);
    }

    //combine partial results
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); ++i)
        outResult.insert(outResult.end(), buffer[i].data.begin(), buffer[i].data.end());

    for (auto& item : buffer)
        item.data.clear();
}
```

**Assembly from the first version:**

```
; 56   :        vector<pr>& localout = id == 0 ? outResult : buffer[id].data;
    test    eax, eax
    jne SHORT $LN19@Process$om
    mov rbx, r13
    jmp SHORT $LN20@Process$om
$LN19@Process$om:
    movsxd  rbx, eax
; File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\vector
; 1505 :         return _My_data._Myfirst[_Pos];
    shl rbx, 6
    add rbx, QWORD PTR ?buffer@@3V?$vector@UmyData@@V?$allocator@UmyData@@@std@@@std@@A
$LN20@Process$om:
; Source.cpp
; 28   :        return data + row * width;
    movzx   ecx, WORD PTR [r15+8]
; 61   :        for (int j = 0; j < inImage.width; ++j)
    xor edi, edi
; 28   :        return data + row * width;
    mov eax, ecx
; 61   :        for (int j = 0; j < inImage.width; ++j)
    mov DWORD PTR j$2[rsp], edi
; 28   :        return data + row * width;
    imul    eax, esi
; 57   : 
; 58   :        //perform some computations to fill buffers
; 59   :        unsigned char* data = inImage.Row(i);
; 60   :        int begin = 0;
    xor ebp, ebp
; 28   :        return data + row * width;
    movsxd  r14, eax
    add r14, QWORD PTR [r15]
; 61   :        for (int j = 0; j < inImage.width; ++j)
    test    ecx, ecx
    je  SHORT $LN4@Process$om
$LL8@Process$om:
; 62   :        {
; 63   :            if (data[j] < 20) begin = j;
    movsxd  rax, edi
    movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rax+r14]
    cmp cl, 20
    jae SHORT $LN15@Process$om
    mov ebp, edi
    jmp SHORT $LN6@Process$om
$LN15@Process$om:
; 64   :            else if (data[j] > 190)
    cmp cl, 190                 ; 000000beH
    jbe SHORT $LN6@Process$om
; File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\vector
; 705  :         if (_Mylast != _My_data._Myend) {
    mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rbx+8]
; Source.cpp
; 65   :                localout.emplace_back(j, i, j - begin);
    mov eax, edi
    sub eax, ebp
    mov DWORD PTR $T5[rsp], eax
; File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\vector
; 705  :         if (_Mylast != _My_data._Myend) {
    cmp rdx, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
    je  SHORT $LN8@Process$om
; Source.cpp
; 12   :        : a((unsigned short)a)
    mov WORD PTR [rdx], di
; 13   :        , b((unsigned short)b)
    mov WORD PTR [rdx+2], si
; 14   :        , c((unsigned short)c)
    mov WORD PTR [rdx+4], ax
; File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\vector
; 691  :         ++_Mylast;
    add QWORD PTR [rbx+8], 6
; 706  :             return _Emplace_back_with_unused_capacity(_STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
    jmp SHORT $LN6@Process$om
$LN8@Process$om:
; 707  :         }
; 708  : 
; 709  :         _Ty& _Result = *_Emplace_reallocate(_Mylast, _STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
    lea rax, QWORD PTR $T5[rsp]
    mov rcx, rbx
    lea r9, QWORD PTR i$3[rsp]
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+32], rax
    lea r8, QWORD PTR j$2[rsp]
    call    ??$_Emplace_reallocate@AEAHAEAHH@?$vector@Upr@@V?$allocator@Upr@@@std@@@std@@QEAAPEAUpr@@QEAU2@AEAH1$$QEAH@Z ; std::vector<pr,std::allocator<pr> >::_Emplace_reallocate<int &,int &,int>
$LN6@Process$om:
; Source.cpp
; 61   :        for (int j = 0; j < inImage.width; ++j)
    movzx   eax, WORD PTR [r15+8]
    inc edi
    mov DWORD PTR j$2[rsp], edi
    cmp edi, eax
    jl  SHORT $LL8@Process$om
$LN4@Process$om:
```

**Assembly from the final version:**

```
; 56   :        vector<pr> localout = std::move(id == 0 ? outResult : buffer[id].data);
    test    r15d, r15d
    jne SHORT $LN19@Process$om
    mov rcx, r13
    jmp SHORT $LN20@Process$om
$LN19@Process$om:
    mov rcx, r15
; File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\vector
; 1505 :         return _My_data._Myfirst[_Pos];
    shl rcx, 6
    add rcx, QWORD PTR ?buffer@@3V?$vector@UmyData@@V?$allocator@UmyData@@@std@@@std@@A
$LN20@Process$om:
; 385  :         _Myfirst = _Right._Myfirst;
    mov r8, QWORD PTR [rcx]
    mov QWORD PTR localout$6[rbp-112], r8
; 386  :         _Mylast  = _Right._Mylast;
    mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rcx+8]
    mov QWORD PTR localout$6[rbp-104], rdx
; 387  :         _Myend   = _Right._Myend;
    mov r9, QWORD PTR [rcx+16]
    mov QWORD PTR localout$6[rbp-96], r9
; 388  : 
; 389  :         _Right._Myfirst = pointer();
    mov QWORD PTR [rcx], rsi
; 390  :         _Right._Mylast  = pointer();
    mov QWORD PTR [rcx+8], rsi
; 391  :         _Right._Myend   = pointer();
    mov QWORD PTR [rcx+16], rsi
Source.cpp
; 28   :        return data + row * width;
    movzx   r14d, WORD PTR [rbx+8]
    mov eax, r14d
    imul    eax, edi
    movsxd  r12, eax
    add r12, QWORD PTR [rbx]
; 62   :        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov DWORD PTR j$3[rbp-112], ebx
    test    r14d, r14d
    je  SHORT $LN7@Process$om
    npad    5
$LL8@Process$om:
; 63   :        {
; 64   :            if (data[j] < 20) begin = j;
    movsxd  rax, ebx
    movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rax+r12]
    cmp cl, 20
    jae SHORT $LN15@Process$om
    mov esi, ebx
    jmp SHORT $LN6@Process$om
$LN15@Process$om:
; 65   :            else if (data[j] > 190)
    cmp cl, 190                 ; 000000beH
    jbe SHORT $LN6@Process$om
; 66   :                localout.emplace_back(j, i, j - begin);
    mov eax, ebx
    sub eax, esi
    mov DWORD PTR $T5[rbp-112], eax
; File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\vector
; 705  :         if (_Mylast != _My_data._Myend) {
    cmp rdx, r9
    je  SHORT $LN21@Process$om
; Source.cpp
; 12   :        : a((unsigned short)a)
    mov WORD PTR [rdx], bx
; 13   :        , b((unsigned short)b)
    mov WORD PTR [rdx+2], di
; 14   :        , c((unsigned short)c)
    mov WORD PTR [rdx+4], ax
; File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\vector
; 691  :         ++_Mylast;
    add rdx, 6
    mov QWORD PTR localout$6[rbp-104], rdx
; 706  :             return _Emplace_back_with_unused_capacity(_STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
    jmp SHORT $LN6@Process$om
$LN21@Process$om:
; 707  :         }
; 708  : 
; 709  :         _Ty& _Result = *_Emplace_reallocate(_Mylast, _STD forward<_Valty>(_Val)...);
    lea rax, QWORD PTR $T5[rbp-112]
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+32], rax
    lea r9, QWORD PTR i$2[rbp-112]
    lea r8, QWORD PTR j$3[rbp-112]
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR localout$6[rbp-112]
    call    ??$_Emplace_reallocate@AEAHAEAHH@?$vector@Upr@@V?$allocator@Upr@@@std@@@std@@QEAAPEAUpr@@QEAU2@AEAH1$$QEAH@Z ; std::vector<pr,std::allocator<pr> >::_Emplace_reallocate<int &,int &,int>
    mov r9, QWORD PTR localout$6[rbp-96]
    mov rdx, QWORD PTR localout$6[rbp-104]
$LN6@Process$om:
; Source.cpp
; 62   :        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
    inc ebx
    mov DWORD PTR j$3[rbp-112], ebx
    cmp ebx, r14d
    jl  SHORT $LL8@Process$om
    mov r8, QWORD PTR localout$6[rbp-112]
$LN7@Process$om:
; 67   :        }
; 68   : 
; 69   :        localout.swap(id == 0 ? outResult : buffer[id].data);
```

Comment: Are you compiling with `-O3` (or equivalent)?

Comment: A `vector<vector<myData>>` is never what you want when you want performance.  Each row is it's own object and can be **anywhere** in memory.  This means you lose data locality which can trounce your cache which would lead to these type of results.  Instead, wrap a `vector<myData>` in a class and use math to pretend that it is 2d.

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<myData>>` or a flat `std::vector` avoid this drawback of a nested vector

Comment: @NathanOliver, I need vector of vectors to process the data in parallel and keep the order of elements correct when executing in parallel

Comment: @ChrisMM - yes, Release x64 build with all default optimizations enabled.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Unfortunately in this case it is not possible, because I execute the code in parallel and I don't know the final amount of elements in each vector in advance, I need also to keep the order of elements correct. And pushing data to a single std::vector from multiple threads would be even worse and requires mutex.

Comment: Could Windows sometimes be scheduling two threads on the same physical core when there are free physical cores, leading to those two threads getting behind so the other threads have to wait for them?  Perfect scheduling over a 100ms interval for startup and end might be a problem, IDK.  Your init loop should be enough to warm up CPU frequency.  (And desktop Intel CPUs run all their cores at the same frequency, so you don't need to warm up all the cores to get them to max turbo.)

Comment: If false sharing was a real problem before padding to put them in separate cache lines, that might indicate that your compiler failed to optimize updates to the inner `vector<pr>` pointer members out of the loop, and is actually writing them to memory every inner-loop iteration.

Comment: For me on GNU/Linux with GCC9.2 `-O3 -fopenmp` (without -march=native or anything), i7-6700k (4c8t configured for 3.9GHz max turbo), compiling for x86-64 of course, I get pretty consistent results: the first printed time varies (73 to 131ms), but quickly settles down to 60ms.  `perf stat` says average IPC = 0.58, 12.5% branch miss rate, and not many L3 loads.  L1d miss rate is ~5.45% of loads.  (Not measuring stores.)  But `perf` doesn't count store events by default.

Comment: @PeterCordes you were right, there is something with the reference to a vector data. When I change the reference to: `vector<pr> localout = std::move(buffer[id].data);` and after the most inner loop add: `localout.swap(buffer[id].data);` then it is always fast. But if i look in assembly then there is still store. Before it was: `add qword ptr[rbx+0x8], 0x6` and now it is: `add rdx, 0x6` `mov qword ptr [rbp-0x18], rdx`, but assembly before jump to reallocate is a bit simpler now. (looks like condition: size == capacity is on registers now. Before it required load for both parameters)

Comment: The 2nd version is much better: the loop-carried latency is only through a register (1 cycle latency); storing it repeatedly isn't a big problem; L1 cache will absorb that just fine.  But the first version bottlenecks on store-forwarding store/reload latency, and can't run the next loop iteration until after waiting for the store/reload (even with store forwarding that's ~6 cycles)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks a lot for the tiny details (thats what I expected as the answer of this question), now the program works stable on speed 49ms. It is not a problem now, but is it explainable why in some program runs I wasn't able to run program faster than e.g. 118ms ?

Comment: IDK.  Maybe some quirk of alignment of dynamic allocations?  Put the asm difference from your comment into the question and I can repost my comment as an answer to that part at least.

Comment: @PeterCordes. I have tried to force reallocation, but without any positive effect on performance. Anyway, I have updated my post with assembly generated from both versions. (just the important OMP part)